# Naming convention for SQL tables under certain circumstances

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions

I'm currently creating the database schema for a new Rails project and I want to things right, so I better ask!

Imagine this: I have a table called "*articles*" and these articles should have tags. The thing I would do now is relatively simple. Create another table called "*tags*" and a third one called "*article_tags*".
Every article and tag has a unique id and "*article_tags*" is the mapping table which brings the right article ids and tag ids together.

**Tables:**

```
- articles
- tags
- article_tags (mapping)
```

The "problem" I currently have is this: Not only articles have tags but also my "*users*" (another table). These tags have to be in two different tables which would then result in some pretty odd naming.

**Tables:**

```
- articles
- article_tags (no mapping)
- article_article_tags (mapping???)

- users
- user_tags (no mapping)
- user_user_tags (mapping???)
```

**Do you have any (general) tips how to improve the naming** of these tables because what you can see above doesn't make me very happy...

Comment: Are the tags the same for the articles and the users?

Comment: Nope, that's why I need two tables for the tags :(

Comment: instead of repeating the word, I'd use the plural versions for the first instances of them; like `articles_article_tags`; it might feel a little weird until you get accustomed to it, but can easily be read as `"articles' article_tags`". ...or you could have a single `tags` table with a column to specify "tag type".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) to do it, something like this:

```
class User
  has_many :taggings, as: :taggable
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end

class Article
  has_many :taggings, as: :taggable
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end

class Tagging
  belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Tag
end
```

So you just need 4 tables: users, articles, taggings, tags.